# How to tell Hibernate to conditionally ignore columns in CRUD operations

Tags: java, database, hibernate, annotations

**Is it possible to somehow tell Hibernate to conditionally ignore a missing column in a database table while doing the CRUD operations?**

I've got a Java application using Hibernate as persistence layer. I'd like to be able to somehow tell Hibernate: *If database version < 50, then ignore this column annotation (or set it transient)*.

This situation arises due to different database versions at different clients, but same entity code for all sites. For example, I've got a class, where the column `description2` might miss in some databases.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer serialNo;    
    private String pickCode;
    private String description1;
    private String description2;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Serial_No", nullable = false)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    public Integer getSerialNo() {
        return this.serialNo;
    }

    @Column(name = "Pick_Code", length = 25)
    public String getPickCode() {
        return this.pickCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "Description1")
    public String getDescription1() {
        return this.description1;
    }

    @Column(name = "Description2")     // <- this column might miss in some databases
    //@TransientIf(...)  <- something like this would be nice, or any other solution
    public String getDescription2() {
        return this.description2;
    }
}
```

**Background:** I have a large application with a lot of customizations for different clients. Now it happens from time to time that one client (out of lets say 500) gets a new feature that requires a database structure update (e.g. a new field in a table). I release a new version for him, he runs a database schema update and can use the new feature. But all other clients won't do an incremental database update each time when any user gets a new feature. They just want to use the latest version, but are affected by the new feature (for that one client) they will never use.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is only possible if you separate the mapping definition from the entities so that you can replace it. Thus you can not use annotation based mapping.

Instead I would suggest to use xml based mapping and create different xml mapping files for each client. Since you have about 500 clients you might want to create groups of clients who all share the same mapping file.

At least I think it will be very hard to maintain the different clients needs with one entity model and it will lead to a complex code structure. E.g. if you add properties to the enties that can be null for some clients than you will also add a lot more null checks to your code. One null check for each client specific property.